# OAuth Verification Failed: Verification of signature failed (Schoology API)

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-1.0a

I'm attempting to build an app for the students at my school using the schoology API, and when trying to get a request token, I get the "OAuth Verification Failed: Verification of signature failed" error. I'm using express to access the API, my code is as follows:

```
function getToken(key, secret){


    var token;
    var parameters = {
        Authorization: 'OAuth',
        realm: 'Schoology API',
        oauth_consumer_key: key,
        oauth_nonce: nonce(20),
        oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now()/1000),
        oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_version: '1.0',

    }
    function generateBaseString(httpMethod, url, parameters){
        var encodeURL = encodeURIComponent(url);

        var paramList = [];
        var paramString = '';
        console.log("Unencoded key: " + parameters['oauth_consumer_key']);
        console.log("Encoded key: " + encodeURIComponent(parameters['oauth_consumer_key']));
        for(var k in parameters) {
            console.log(k + ' Added to base string: ' + encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(parameters[k]));
            paramList.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(parameters[k]));
        }
        paramString = encodeURIComponent(paramList.sort().join('&'));

        return httpMethod + '&' + encodeURL + '&' + paramString;
    }


    base_string = generateBaseString('GET', 'https://api.schoology.com/v1/oauth/request_token', parameters);
    oauth_string = secret + '&';

    var signature = (new Buffer(hmacsha1(oauth_string, base_string))).toString('base64');
    console.log("Signature is " + signature);
    console.log("Base string is " + base_string);
    console.log("Oauth string is " + oauth_string);
    var header = {
        Authorization: 'OAuth',
        realm: parameters.realm,
        oauth_consumer_key: parameters.oauth_consumer_key,
        oauth_nonce: parameters.oauth_nonce,
        oauth_signature_method: parameters.oauth_signature_method,
        oauth_timestamp: parameters.oauth_timestamp,
        oauth_version: parameters.oauth_version,
        oauth_signature: signature,
        oauth_callback: 'oob'
    }


    var options = {
        hostname: 'api.schoology.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/v1/oauth/request_token',
        method: 'GET',
        header: header,
    }

    var url =   'https://api.schoology.com/v1/oauth/request_token?' + 
                'Authorization=OAuth' +
                'realm=' + parameters.realm +
                '&oauth_consumer_key=' + parameters.oauth_consumer_key + 
                '&oauth_nonce=' + parameters.oauth_nonce +
                '&oauth_signature_method=' + parameters.oauth_signature_method +
                '&oauth_timestamp=' + parameters.oauth_timestamp +
                '&oauth_version=' + parameters.oauth_version +
                '&oauth_signature=' + signature +
                '&oauth_callback=' + 'oob'
    ;
    console.log("URL: " + url);
    // return
    var req = https.request(url, (res) => {
        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('headers:', res.headers);

        let data = '';
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            console.log("DATA");
            data += d;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            token = JSON.parse(data);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', (e => {
        console.error("Error: " + e.message);
    }));

    req.end();


    return token;
}
```

The response header contains a 401 error. Using POST returns a 405 error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just got oath working with Schoology -- you have a couple of options:

1. Since the request is sent HTTPS (secure) they will accept a PLAINTEXT signature method with a simpler `<consumer-secret>&<token-secret>` signature.
2. If you want to use the HMAC signature method, the parameters you are sending do not look quite like what they are using for the `baseString`. If you examine the response body you get with 401, you can see what their server used as the base string and compare that to yours.

I doubt that sending the Authorization as url params will work. You need to build one string to send as the "Authorization" header that looks about like this:

```
OAuth realm="Schoology API",oauth_consumer_key="(your consumer key)",oauth_token="",oauth_nonce="(some random string)",oauth_timestamp="1599876905",oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="(your consumer secret)%26"
```